# Terraform - Optional SSM parameter lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm doing a lookup for an SSM parameter which may or may not exist depending on a variable passed in:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "server_tags" {
  name  = "/${var.env_number}/server_tags"
}
```

I am then using it like below in my locals and passing to my module:

```
locals {
  server_tags = data.aws_ssm_parameter.server_tags != null ? jsondecode(data.aws_ssm_parameter.server_tags.value) : {}
  instance_tags = merge(var.instance_tags, local.server_tags)
}
```

This works fine when my parameter exists, but if I pass in a value where my parameter doesn't exist, I get an error:

```
Error describing SSM parameter (/997/server_tags): ParameterNotFound:
```

Is there anyway I can do a pre-check to see if the parameter exists or make it optional somehow?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot catch an error from a `data` block, but it is possible to make it optional based on an input value for a declared variable. Does that sound ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly you **can't do this**. There is no way build-on mechanism for TF to check if a data source exists or not. But you can program your own logic for that using [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source).

Since you program the external data source, you can create a logic for checking if a resource exists or not.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't find a solution but I just made sure the resource existed