# Terraform: Use default variable if parameter store value doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Overview**

- using Terraform cloud.
- seed variable "environment" specified in Terraform cloud workspace e.g dev/test/prod
- The "environment" variable is used to look up values in AWS parameter store e.g.

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "rds_password" {
  name = "/${var.environment}/rds/pg/rds_password"
}

module "db" {
  password               = data.aws_ssm_parameter.rds_password.value
}
```

**Question**

What's the best way to go about setting default values?  It seems as though using locals to check for the existence of the parameter otherwise use the default var.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform - Optional SSM parameter lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018268/terraform-optional-ssm-parameter-lookup)

Answer (score 1):

I created a lookup, which maps to a given value.  I'd be keen to know if there is a better way.

```
locals.tf
locals {
    resources = {
        production    = "production"
        qa            = "default"
        dev           = "default"
    }
}
```

```
data.tf
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "db_instance_class" {
    name = "/${local.resources[var.environment]}/myapplication/resources/db/instance_class"
}
```

```
SSM Parameter store
/default/myapplication/resources/db/instance_class
/production/myapplication/resources/db/instance_class
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question: The poster wants to know how to use a default value if the parameter does NOT exist in SSM. Setting additional parameters in SSM is irrelevant.

Comment: @NR This _is_ the original poster.

Comment: No, self-answers are completely valid. As long as this answer solves OP's problem, it should stay here in the answer section. If someone else can provide an alternative/better approach, they can post another answer.